# Polly policyretry resultcondition and exception wrapper c#

Tags: c#, wrapper, polly

[Wrapper around Polly Framework so that implementation can stay at a single place](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47670390/wrapper-around-polly-framework-so-that-implementation-can-stay-at-a-single-place)

I am able to create a wrapper based on the above link . but i am not sure how can i make this as generic .
I want to have this wrapper for more than result bool check such as handling exception too.

Here is my code:

```cs
public class RetryWrapper
{
    public static bool Execute(Func<bool> func)
    {
        RetryPolicy<bool> retryPolicyNeedsTrueResponse =
            Policy.HandleResult<bool>(b => b != true)
                .WaitAndRetry(new[]
                {
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                        TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
                });
        return retryPolicyNeedsTrueResponse.Execute(func);
    }
}
```

Any help is much appreciated. Thanks in advance

Comment: Can you elaborate more on this "*such as handling exception too*"

Comment: @TheGeneral  i was looking for to handle any exception also in addition to the bool check

Comment: @Rocky3151 If you need to check other conditions than the wrapped operation's result then you can use the `Or<T>()` builder function. Just like this: `.HandleResult<bool>(b => b != true).Or<Exception>().WaitAndRetry(...`

Comment: @PeterCsala thanks .  i have only one function that returns bool. In the below code ,how do i call the below generic code . i am still a beginner . any example would  help me to understand

Comment: @Rocky3151 `Execute<bool>(func, b => b != true)` So the `HandleResult`'s delegate comes from the `Execute`'s second parameter.

Comment: @PeterCsala . thanks so much . i will try that . have a good day

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To make it generic, I guess you could do something like this

```
public static T Execute<T>(Func<T> func, Func<T,bool> success)
{
    RetryPolicy<T> retryPolicyNeedsTrueResponse =
            Policy.HandleResult<T>(b => success(T))
                .WaitAndRetry(new[]
                {
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10),
                    TimeSpan.FromSeconds(15)
                });
    return retryPolicyNeedsTrueResponse.Execute(func);
}
```

<sub>***Note** : the benefit of this seems to be iffy and suspect at best, also you would need another version for `async`*</sub>.

You could probably just get away with an array of timespan, reuse that, and let your code be more declarative and adaptable to all the other features of polly.

<sub>***Note 2** : This is completely untested*</sub>.

Comment: sorry. its giving me an error at success(T) .T is a type which is not valid in a given context

Comment: @Rocky3151 Just change `success(T)` to `success(b)`

Comment: @PeterCsala Thanks very much .